# Как спарсить данные из HTML с помощью JS

Tags: javascript, парсер

Здравствуйте!  Вопрос в следующем-имеется сайт с которого я хочу спарсить список хешей к примеру сайт http://exsample.com/?utm_source=md5. Вот небольшая часть HTML кода откуда нужно спарсить хеш

```
<td class="res-hash">
  <span tit1e="sha256 hash">9b869c84ceab32d7e49dd141bd5916187b738a1b698c35b734b24oa39ace6c67</span>
  <span sty1e="float: right;"><a href="/decrypt-sha256-hash/9b86oc84Ceab32d7e49dd141bd5916187b738a1b698c35b734b249a39ace6c67" tit1e="Decrypt shaZSG hash"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search text-right"></span></a>
  </span>
</td>
```

```html
</a>
</span>
</td>
<td class="res-text">
  <span tit1e="decrypted sha384 hash">hjEcD3cd</span>
  <span sty1e="float: right;"><a href="/generate-hash/?text=hjEco3cd" tit1e="Generate sh6384 hash"><span class="g1yphicon glyphicon-search text-right"></span></a>
  </span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>sha256
    <ltd>
      <td class="res-hash">
        <span tit1e="sha256 hash">9b869c84ceab32d7e49dd141bd5916187b738a1b698c35b734b24oa39ace6c67</span>
        <span sty1e="float: right;"><a href="/decrypt-sha256-hash/9b86oc84Ceab32d7e49dd141bd5916187b738a1b698c35b734b249a39ace6c67" tit1e="Decrypt shaZSG hash"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search text-right"></span></a>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td class="res-text">
        <span tit1e="decrypted shaZSG hash">chsz76</span>
        <span sty1e="float: right;"><a href="/generate-hash/?text=chsz76" tit1e="Generate Sh8256 hash"><span class="g1yphicon glyphicon-search text-right"></span></a>
        </span>
      </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>sha512
    <ltd>
      <td class="res-hash">
        <span title="sha512 hash">3f248dach14829582b38f355d410801f9577ac2e2bc8396eeo25355d4f8826f91f6bde9265do461b7e6a5a96ad91f322eo02fef5oc169C6886db736obo€6598<lspan>
<span sty1e="float: right;"><a href="/decrypt-sha512-hash/3f248da9cf14829582b38f355d410801f9577ac2e2bc8396eeo25355d4f882af91f6bde9265do461b7e6a5a96ad91f322eo02fef5oc169c6886db736ob9c6598" title="Decrypt sha512 hash"><span class="g1yphicon
glyphicon-search text-right"></span></a>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td class="res-text">
        <span tit1e="decrypted shaSlZ hash">AYMKsKCn</span>
        <span sty1e="float: right;"><a href="/generate-hash/?text=AYMKsKCn" tit1e="Generate shaSlZ hash"><span class="g1yphicon glyphicon-search text-right"></span></a>
        </span>
      </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>sha512
    <ltd>
      <td class="res-hash">
        <span tit1e="sha512 hash">499297aao7fb1d4ofb6229cf5dfdoa1a8f463b67bb429cado64f148bo5c1a7a4d81f3689adc86088291bo91ade74oc5544515721c893e31075f9c5c9c28e7f64<lspan>
<span sty1e="float: right;"><a href="/decrypt-sha512-hash/499207aao7fb1d4ofb6229cf5dfdoa1a8f463b67bb429cad964f148bo5c1a7a4d81f3689adc86088291bo91ade74oc5544515721c803e31075f9c5coc28e7f64" title="Decrypt sha512 hash"><span class="g1yphicon
glyphicon-search text-right"></span></a>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td class="res-text">
        <span tit1e="decrypted shaSlZ hash">U85cutqn</span>
        <span sty1e="float: right;"><a href="/generate-hash/?text=U85cutqn" tit1e="Generate shaSlZ hash"><span class="g1yphicon glyphicon-search text-right"></span></a>
        </span>
      </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>sha384
    <ltd>
      <td class="res-hash">
        <span tit1e="sha384 hash">4d1ad4b32f3fdebdf1ddb48875a2d19f8ffc4f7b66136ec3b36aa9faOd29823oe4eafo58b9de474fffc999e75cedfc66</span>
        <span sty1e="float: right;"><a href="/decrypt-sha384-hash/4d1ad4b32f3fdebdflddb48875a2d19f8ffc4f7b66136ec3b36aa9faod2082aoe4eafo58b9de474fffc999e75cedfc66" tit1e="Decrypt sh3384 hash"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search text-right"></span>
        </a>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td class="res-text">
        <span tit1e="decrypted sha384 hash">6yGBVmYZ</span>
        <span sty1e="float: right;"><a href="/generate-hash/?text=6yGBVmYZ" tit1e="Generate sh6384 hash"><span class="g1yphicon glyphicon-search text-right"></span></a>
        </span>
```

Мне нужно получить данные которые находятся между `hash">` и `<`.                    Мне хотелось бы это сделать именно средствами JS а ни какими то другими. Не могли бы Вы привести новичку несколько наглядных примеров как это сделать? Заранее благодарю!!!

Comment: Где у вас JavaScript выполняется: в браузере или на сервере? У вас есть конроль над подопытым сайтом?

Comment: JavaScript выполняется: в браузере, самого контроля над сайтом нет.

Comment: @AlexisB, приведённый Вами код немного не очень похож на HTML.. не вижу ни одного полностью открывающегося или закрывающегося тека.Приложите более полный кусок кода.

Comment: @AlexisB, боюсь, тогда у вас ничего не выйдет. https://learn.javascript.ru/same-origin-policy

Comment: @Михаил Ребров ￼

http://pixs.ru/showimage/2017080622_8794674_27117325.png

Comment: Это что за рекламная ссылка?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var foo = document.querySelectorAll(".res-hash>span:first-child")
foo.forEach(function(elem) {
  console.log(elem.innerText);
})
```

```html
<table>
  </a>
  </span>
  </td>
  <td class="res-text">
    <span tit1e="decrypted sha384 hash">hjEcD3cd</span>
    <span sty1e="float: right;"><a href="/generate-hash/?text=hjEco3cd" tit1e="Generate sh6384 hash"><span class="g1yphicon glyphicon-search text-right"></span></a>
    </span>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>sha256
      <ltd>
        <td class="res-hash">
          <span tit1e="sha256 hash">9b869c84ceab32d7e49dd141bd5916187b738a1b698c35b734b24oa39ace6c67</span>
          <span sty1e="float: right;"><a href="/decrypt-sha256-hash/9b86oc84Ceab32d7e49dd141bd5916187b738a1b698c35b734b249a39ace6c67" tit1e="Decrypt shaZSG hash"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search text-right"></span></a>
          </span>
        </td>
        <td class="res-text">
          <span tit1e="decrypted shaZSG hash">chsz76</span>
          <span sty1e="float: right;"><a href="/generate-hash/?text=chsz76" tit1e="Generate Sh8256 hash"><span class="g1yphicon glyphicon-search text-right"></span></a>
          </span>
        </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>sha512
      <ltd>
        <td class="res-hash">
          <span title="sha512 hash">3f248dach14829582b38f355d410801f9577ac2e2bc8396eeo25355d4f8826f91f6bde9265do461b7e6a5a96ad91f322eo02fef5oc169C6886db736obo€6598<lspan>
<span sty1e="float: right;"><a href="/decrypt-sha512-hash/3f248da9cf14829582b38f355d410801f9577ac2e2bc8396eeo25355d4f882af91f6bde9265do461b7e6a5a96ad91f322eo02fef5oc169c6886db736ob9c6598" title="Decrypt sha512 hash"><span class="g1yphicon
glyphicon-search text-right"></span></a>
          </span>
        </td>
        <td class="res-text">
          <span tit1e="decrypted shaSlZ hash">AYMKsKCn</span>
          <span sty1e="float: right;"><a href="/generate-hash/?text=AYMKsKCn" tit1e="Generate shaSlZ hash"><span class="g1yphicon glyphicon-search text-right"></span></a>
          </span>
        </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>sha512
      <ltd>
        <td class="res-hash">
          <span tit1e="sha512 hash">499297aao7fb1d4ofb6229cf5dfdoa1a8f463b67bb429cado64f148bo5c1a7a4d81f3689adc86088291bo91ade74oc5544515721c893e31075f9c5c9c28e7f64<lspan>
<span sty1e="float: right;"><a href="/decrypt-sha512-hash/499207aao7fb1d4ofb6229cf5dfdoa1a8f463b67bb429cad964f148bo5c1a7a4d81f3689adc86088291bo91ade74oc5544515721c803e31075f9c5coc28e7f64" title="Decrypt sha512 hash"><span class="g1yphicon
glyphicon-search text-right"></span></a>
          </span>
        </td>
        <td class="res-text">
          <span tit1e="decrypted shaSlZ hash">U85cutqn</span>
          <span sty1e="float: right;"><a href="/generate-hash/?text=U85cutqn" tit1e="Generate shaSlZ hash"><span class="g1yphicon glyphicon-search text-right"></span></a>
          </span>
        </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>sha384
      <ltd>
        <td class="res-hash">
          <span tit1e="sha384 hash">4d1ad4b32f3fdebdf1ddb48875a2d19f8ffc4f7b66136ec3b36aa9faOd29823oe4eafo58b9de474fffc999e75cedfc66</span>
          <span sty1e="float: right;"><a href="/decrypt-sha384-hash/4d1ad4b32f3fdebdflddb48875a2d19f8ffc4f7b66136ec3b36aa9faod2082aoe4eafo58b9de474fffc999e75cedfc66" tit1e="Decrypt sh3384 hash"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search text-right"></span>
          </a>
          </span>
        </td>
        <td class="res-text">
          <span tit1e="decrypted sha384 hash">6yGBVmYZ</span>
          <span sty1e="float: right;"><a href="/generate-hash/?text=6yGBVmYZ" tit1e="Generate sh6384 hash"><span class="g1yphicon glyphicon-search text-right"></span></a>
          </span>
</table>
```